# TypeError when running first Jest/Puppeteer test

Tags: npm, jestjs, puppeteer

I am trying to integrate Jest and Puppeteer on Ubuntu. I have followed carefully this tutorial [Using with puppeteer](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer.html#custom-example-without-jest-puppeteer-preset) but I get this error when running my first test:

```
# npm test
[...]
 FAIL  ./test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run    
    TypeError: TestEnvironment is not a constructor
      at node_modules/jest-runner/build/run_test.js:88:25
```

Here is how I setup the environment of my project:

```
~# mkdir jest-lab
~# cd jest-lab/
~/jest-lab# npm init -y
~/jest-lab# npm install --save-dev jest-puppeteer puppeteer jest
```

Then I copied and pasted the files from the tutorial [Using with puppeteer](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer.html#custom-example-without-jest-puppeteer-preset).

I had to customize a bit the file setup.js to add the option "{args: ['--no-sandbox']}".

Here are all my project files:

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  globalSetup: './setup.js',
  globalTeardown: './teardown.js',
  testEnvironment: './puppeteer_environment.js',
};
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "jest-lab",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^3.7.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
      "verbose": true
  }
}
```

**puppeteer_environment.js:**

```
// puppeteer_environment.js
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const os = require('os');

const DIR = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'jest_puppeteer_global_setup');

class PuppeteerEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config);
  }

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    // get the wsEndpoint
    const wsEndpoint = fs.readFileSync(path.join(DIR, 'wsEndpoint'), 'utf8');
    if (!wsEndpoint) {
      throw new Error('wsEndpoint not found');
    }

    // connect to puppeteer
    this.global.__BROWSER__ = await puppeteer.connect({
      browserWSEndpoint: wsEndpoint,
    });
  }

  async teardown() {
    await super.teardown();
  }

  runScript(script) {
    return super.runScript(script);
  }
}
```

**setup.js (customized to run chrome with --no-sandbox):**

```
// setup.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');

const DIR = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'jest_puppeteer_global_setup');

module.exports = async function() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
  // store the browser instance so we can teardown it later
  // this global is only available in the teardown but not in TestEnvironments
  global.__BROWSER_GLOBAL__ = browser;

  // use the file system to expose the wsEndpoint for TestEnvironments
  mkdirp.sync(DIR);
  fs.writeFileSync(path.join(DIR, 'wsEndpoint'), browser.wsEndpoint());
};
```

**teardown.js:**

```
// teardown.js
const os = require('os');
const rimraf = require('rimraf');
const path = require('path');

const DIR = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'jest_puppeteer_global_setup');
module.exports = async function() {
  // close the browser instance
  await global.__BROWSER_GLOBAL__.close();

  // clean-up the wsEndpoint file
  rimraf.sync(DIR);
};
```

**And finally here is test file test.js:**

```
// test.js
const timeout = 5000;

describe(
  '/ (Home Page)',
  () => {
    let page;
    beforeAll(async () => {
      page = await global.__BROWSER__.newPage();
      await page.goto('https://google.com');
    }, timeout);

    it('should load without error', async () => {
      const text = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.textContent);
      expect(text).toContain('google');
    });
  },
  timeout,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following at the end of "puppeteer_environment.js"

```
module.exports = PuppeteerEnvironment;
```